# VBA replace and add cells wit condition while comparing two sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a principal sheet (Launch Tracker) that needs to be updated from a database. I have put the extraction of the database on an adjacent sheet (LAT - Master Data).

What I would like to do is that if the value of the columns H, O, Q are similar then it would replace the lines from column "E" to "AL" on the (Launch Tracker), if there is no match I would like to add the entire line at the end of the (Launch Tracker) sheet.

I already have this code that was running when I made a test, but now it doesn't seem to be working and I cannot figure out why.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Dim Ttrak_concat, Tdata_concat, Derlig As Integer
Sub General_update()
Dim Cptr As Integer, D_concat As Object, Ref As String, Ligne As Integer, Lig As Integer
Dim Start As Single
Dim test 'for trials
    Start = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call concatenate("LAT - Master Data", Tdata_concat)
    Call concatenate("Launch Tracker", Ttrak_concat)
    'collection
    Set D_concat = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(Ttrak_concat)
    Ref = Ttrak_concat(Cptr, 1)
        If Not D_concat.exists(Ref) Then: D_concat.Add Ref, Ttrak_concat(Cptr, 2)
    Next
    'comparison between the sheets
    Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Activate
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(Tdata_concat)
        Ref = Tdata_concat(Cptr, 1) 'chaineIPR feuil data
        Ligne = Tdata_concat(Cptr, 2) 'localisation sheet data
        If D_concat.exists(Ref) Then
                Lig = D_concat.Item(Ref) 'localisation sheet track
        Else
                Lig = Derlig + 1
        End If
        Sheets("LAT - Master Data").Range(Cells(Ligne, "E"), Cells(Ligne, "AL")).Copy _
                    Sheets("Launch Tracker").Cells(Lig, "E")
    Next
    Sheets("Launch Tracker").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox "mise à jour réalisée en: " & Round(Timer - Start, 2) & " secondes"
End Sub
'---------------------------------------
Sub concatenate(Feuille, Tablo)
Dim T_coli, T_colp, T_colr, Cptr As Integer
Dim test
 With Sheets(Feuille)
        'memorizing columns H O Q
        Derlig = .Columns("H").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        T_coli = Application.Transpose(.Range("H3:H" & Derlig))
        T_colp = Application.Transpose(.Range("O3:O" & Derlig))
        T_colr = Application.Transpose(.Range("Q3:Q" & Derlig))
        'concatenate for comparison
        ReDim Tablo(UBound(T_colr), 2)
        For Cptr = 1 To UBound(T_colr)
           Tablo(Cptr, 1) = T_coli(Cptr) & " " & T_colp(Cptr) & " " & T_colr(Cptr)
           Tablo(Cptr, 2) = Cptr + 2
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Would someone have the solution to my problem?

Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT 11:48**

Actually the code runs now but It doesn't work the way I need it to. I would like to update the information on my sheet Launch tracker from the LAT - Master data sheet when the three columns H, O and Q are the same. The problem is that I have checked and some lines present in the LAT - Master Data sheet are not being added into the Launch tracker sheet after running the macro... Does someone have any idea why ?

Agathe

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It bugs on this part ReDim Tablo(UBound(T_colr), 2)

Comment: What does it mean that it "bugs"? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: It says "Type Mismatch"

Comment: Is Derlig = 3 when the error occurs?

Comment: Yes apparently that's where the problem comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type mismatch means that you gave a function a parameter that has the wrong type. In your case that means that `UBound` can't deal with `T_colr` or `ReDim` can'T deal with `UBound(T_colr)`. Since `Ubound` always returns an integer, it must be `T_colr`.

If `Derlig=3` then `Application.Transpose(.Range("Q3:Q" & Derlig))` won't return an array but a single value (`Double`, `String` or whatever). That's when `UBound` throws the error.

You will also get an error with `T_coli(Cptr)` etc.

What you could do to prevent this is to check if `Derlig = 3` and treat that case individually.

```
If Derlig = 3 Then
    ReDim Tablo(1, 2)
    Tablo(1, 1) = T_coli & " " & T_colp & " " & T_colr
    Tablo(1, 2) = 3
Else
    ReDim Tablo(UBound(T_colr), 2)
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(T_colr)
       Tablo(Cptr, 1) = T_coli(Cptr) & " " & T_colp(Cptr) & " " & T_colr(Cptr)
       Tablo(Cptr, 2) = Cptr + 2
    Next Cptr
End If
```

Comment: This is making me crazy ^^ Now apparently my 'If' don't have the proper syntax

Comment: That would be a different issue. `If ...Then`, `Else` and `End If` should all be on individual lines. You need to make sure the `If`, `For` and `With` blocks are properly placed. I added the for loop to my answer.

Comment: You are the best ! I need to do something about my poor VBA skills, but thank you for your help. It works :)

Comment: Ok actually I have another problem... Could you check the edit please ?